# Listings language definition keyword suffixes

Tags: formatting, listings

I'm trying to create a `listings` language definition for ARM assembly and many of the instructions have prefixes/suffixes (i.e. BGT, BLE, BNE, BEQ branch instructions).

Is there a way to define B with any suffix as a keyword?  Or am I stuck adding every combination of prefix/suffix/instruction in my list of keywords?

Comment: Related Question: [Listings: text highlighting based on prefix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137237/listings-text-highlighting-based-on-prefix).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `keywordsprefix=<prefix>` to specify that anything beginning with the  `<prefix>` is considered a a keyword. The MWE below highlights any word beginning with `B` in blue, but leaves other text alone:

[image]

However you should note the following limitations form the listings documentation:

> 1. The prefix is always case sensitive.
> 2. Only one prefix can be defined at a time.
> 3. If used standalone outside a language definition, the key might work only after selecting a nonempty language (and switching back to the empty language if necessary).
> 4. The key does not respect the value of `classoffset` and has no optional class  argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{%
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!20},%
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,%
    numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=2, numbersep=5pt,%
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    language=Java,
    keywordsprefix=B,
    }%

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
    ABC BGT DEF
    BLE XYZ MWS
    BNE DNW QES
    ABN BEQ MWE
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was also looking for a language definition for the **ARM assembler** and I came up with building the (huge) list of all keywords.

The result, including the python script to generate the keywords is on [github](https://github.com/frosc/arm-assembler-latex-listings).