# How to I emphazise all words beginning with ` in an lstlisting

Tags: listings, keywords

I use a preprocesser to process some code before my verilog compiler.
All preprocesser words start with the `` ` `` character

Example:

```
`pp_if
```

unfortunately its possible to define your own preprocessor words. The only thing that is known is that the word starts with `` ` ``.

How can I highlight any word starting with `` ` ``?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adapt the solution from [Listings language definition keyword suffixes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44914/listings-language-definition-keyword-suffixes)
and use the `keywordsprefix=<prefix>` to specify that anything beginning with
tick is considered a keyword:

[image]

### Notes:

- To obtain the a more reasonable display of leading tick, I added `upquote=true` which requires the `textcomp` package.  There may be a better way to handle the issue of displaying the `` ` ``.
- There are limitations of using `keywordsprefix=<prefix>` which are noted in [Listings language definition keyword suffixes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44914/listings-language-definition-keyword-suffixes).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\lstset{%
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!20},%
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,%
    numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=2, numbersep=5pt,%
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    language=Java,
    keywordsprefix=`,
    upquote=true,
    }%

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
    `pp_if pp rr
    pp_if `mm zz
    xx `MM PP
    abc def ghi
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok know it gets a bit tricky. i want to do the words starting with ` a different color than the other keywords. I tried with the emph, but then i can't do the prefix stuff.. any suggestions?

Comment: @Rasmus: Since it is called `keywordprefix` (and with the highlighting of restrictions as pointed out in [Listings language definition keyword suffixes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44914/listings-language-definition-keyword-suffixes)) this may not be easily doable, without much hackery (might be useful as a separate question).  One solution might be to copy the code for `keywordprefix` and define `emphstyleprefix` and try to adapt that..

Comment: @Rasmus: Also, if this answered your question you should consider accepting it: [How do you accept an answer?](http://goo.gl/hzFkJ)