# lstinputlistings syntax highlighting

Tags: listings, highlighting, input, syntax

I am using package `listings` to import my Python source code into my LaTeX document. I use the command `\lstinputlistings`. I have a Python source like

```
class MyClass(Yourclass):
    def __init__(self, myvar, yours):
        bla bla bla...
```

What should I write in my `\lstset` command in order to enlight words MyClass, init etc.? I wouldn't want to write any word I want to be highlighted. I tried using `moredelims=[s][\color{teal}]{class}{(}` inside `lstset` but it doesn't work.

And why is `morekeywords={...}` not working with `lstinputlistings`. It does with `lstlistings` environment, but doesn't with input from a source file.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: There is no `moredelims` option. Will `\lstset{language=Python,morekeywords={as,init},  moredelim=*[s][\color{teal}]{MyClass}{)},   moredelim=*[s][\color{teal}]{__}{)}}` work for you? If you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and perhaps post your output or clarify what you are trying to achieve, then you may get better help.

Answer (score 3):

It is always good to post a [minimal and compilable example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), not just code snippets. This way, the answerers do not have to guess what's happening with your problem.

I *guess* that you are looking for something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{language=Python,
        morekeywords={as,__init__,MyClass},
        keywordstyle=\color{teal}\bfseries,
        }
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting{guess.py}
\end{document}
```

where `guess.py` is your sample code snippet. I just added *as* on the last line to show that `morekeywords` works.

```
class MyClass(Yourclass):
    def __init__(self, myvar, yours):
        bla bla bla... as
```

Here is the output.

[image]

You can also remove `__init__` from `morekeywords` option and use the answers in [How to I emphazise all words beginning with ` in an lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83683/how-to-i-emphazise-all-words-beginning-with-in-an-lstlisting) and [Listings language definition keyword suffixes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44914/listings-language-definition-keyword-suffixes). So you may put the following code snippet into your preamble.

```
\lstset{language=Python,
    morekeywords={as,MyClass},
        keywordstyle=\color{teal}\bfseries,
        keywordsprefix=_,
        }
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: It does work, thank you. Anyway I was looking for a solution which is not depending on single words I write into my keywords...I found the best the solution in another discussion: package minted

Answer (score 0):

To sidestep your `listinputlistings` issue, you can always place do

```
\begin{lstlisting}
\input{yoursource}
\end{lstlisting}
```

or do a command like so:

```
\newcommand{\Source}[1]{\begin{lstlisting}\input{#1}\end{lstlisting}}
```

As far as adding more keywords, I mucked around with it a while ago and came up with

```
\lstset{emph={Keyword1, Keyword2, Etc}, emphstyle={\bf}}
```

I am not sure if this allows you to change the colors, however.

Comment: I already tried using emph but not without issues, for example the word `as` is not recognized by listings. If you try setting in emph, you will have `as` highlighted in all of your comments and even in the word clASs...anyway the input command seems to work, I haven't actually thought about that before.

Comment: Well, that's silly. I'll keep looking for a real solution.