# Listings: text highlighting based on prefix

Tags: listings

How can I apply different styles to keywords depending on their prefix?

Here is some sample code:

```
(-2,0,0) (2,1,1) op-registerbox !box1
;box1 /Blue op-setproperties
```

I'd like to typeset

1. words starting with `!` and `;` in color red,
2. words starting with `/` in color green,
3. words starting with `cp-` in bold.

So far, this is what I've got:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{XX}
{
basicstyle=\small\sffamily\fontseries{c},
emphstyle=\underbar,
keywordsprefix=[2]{/},
alsoletter={/},
keywordstyle=\textbf,
keywordstyle=[2]\color{green},
morekeywords={op,registerbox, ...},
morestring=[b][\color{green}]",
columns=flexible,
escapechar=\%,
numbersep=6pt,
numberstyle=\scriptsize
}
```

I'm aware that only one `keywordsprefix` can be defined at the moment: specifying more than one class of prefix (`keywordsprefix=[2]{/}`) is currently not supported.
I'd like to avoid having to list all the words that match my description into `morekeywords`. Is that possible? How?

Comment: Related Question: [Listings language definition keyword suffixes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44914/listings-language-definition-keyword-suffixes).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way of doing it using `moredelim`. I assumed you meant *words starting with `op-`*, not *words starting with `cp-`*. I didn't use `keywordsprefix` because it currently only allows for one prefix "class", and the `listings` documentation (v1.5b) still considers it a buggy feature; see subsection 4.18 about that.

Remember to load `lmodern` if you want some stuff to be typeset in bold typewriter font.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{XX}
{
basicstyle=\small\sffamily\fontseries{c},
morestring=[b][\color{green}]",
%
moredelim=[s][\color{red}]{!}{\ },
moredelim=[s][\color{red}]{;}{\ },
moredelim=[s][\color{ForestGreen}]{/}{\ },
moredelim=[s][\bfseries]{op-}{\ },
%
columns=flexible,
escapechar=\%,
numbersep=6pt,
numberstyle=\scriptsize
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=XX]
(-2,0,0) (2,1,1) op-registerbox !box1
;box1 /Blue op-setproperties
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Neat trick to use a space (`\ `) as terminating delimiter!

Comment: @Daniel Thanks `;p` Please see this somewhat related question of mine: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153896/has-the-time-come-for-a-latex3-successor-to-listings